# mysql - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql

When trying to run this query I get the following message

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`30`' at line 18

I have no idea what this means as my code does not have a line 18 nor does it have '30' so I am unsure as to why it says near '30'

```html
SELECT * from (SELECT myTag 
FROM (SELECT myTag 
FROM sports )
UNION ALL 
(SELECT myTag2 myTag 
FROM sports)  as sport3
UNION ALL 
(SELECT myTag3 myTag 
FROM sports) alltags 
GROUP BY myTag ) as sport
ORDER BY COUNT(*)as sport2)
FROM (SELECT *
    FROM sports b
    join sports a
    on a.myTag = b.Name
    where a.sportID <> b.sportID and a.myTag2 = 'football' or a.myTag = 'football' or a.myTag3 = 'football')
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMUaZ.png)

I want to pick up the most common value from myTag, myTag2 and myTag3 and then use that value and check it with the Name column and is if any of these values match and if they do display the information from that row

Comment: With a union, each query must have the same number and type of columns

Comment: this is my first time using union so I am a little unsure as to how it works, maybe it is best that I don't use it

Comment: What is with all the parens? They seemed to be unbalanced, and there is no apparent reason for them.

Comment: oh right, I was trying to add to queries together and a quite new to this

Comment: I suggest you back up a step, and explain what it is you are attempting to achieve. We can fix the query to avoid a syntax error... but the query we suggest is very likely not going to return the result you are wanting. Please consider providing example data, and the expected output.

Comment: You might want to rethink the whole query. Seems pretty convoluted. Maybe if you stated what you have, and what you want to achieve....

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is that both queries work on their own so I don't understand why I can't just join them together

Comment: I strongly suspect that the second query does not "work on its own". The aggregate (COUNT) in the ORDER BY is going to cause all of the rows to be collapsed into a single row, and the values returned for the expressions in the select list are indeterminate. (The second query would throw an error if sql_mode included ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.) Looks like the result from that is going to contain more than one column, so it can't be UNION to the single column result from the first query. It looks like "the problem" is smashing SQL together hoping it will work.

Comment: oh right, I think I get what you mean

Comment: I have changed my query a little (see question)

Comment: Your query will need to be changed a lot, not a little. What are the results of each query? Are the column names and types identical? If not, change the queries so that they are. And change the ```SELECT *``` to **SELECT _column names_**

Comment: Are you positively sure this is the query MySQL is complaining about? Do you get this error running the SQL shown right in your favourite MySQL client, or it's part of a large application written in some other language?

Comment: Cool story bro. What is the *question*? The updated SQL replaces one reference to `countries` with a reference to `sports`, but it is still an indecipherable mess. It's not at all clear to us what result you expect the query to return. Q: How will you know that the result returned is what you are expecting, and how will you verify that the result is "correct"? With what you've posted, we're *just guessing*. Without **example data** and **expected results**, I'm voting to close as "unclear" what you are asking.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Jesus Christ :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is returning an error because the SQL syntax is invalid.

The opening paren is unbalanced. The reference to "line 18" and  "at '30'" is likely due to the MySQL parser reading *past* what *you think* is the end of the statement, and reading further, looking for valid syntax to parse.

The SQL posted in the question is an indecipherable mess. (It looks like it was thrown together without a plan; mashing SQL constructs together hoping that it will return something useful.)

It's not at all clear what *result* we expect to be returned. And without that, it's not possible to give more concrete assistance. Without *example data* and an *expected result*, we're flying blind, and just guessing at what we are attempting to achieve.

**EDIT**

The question has been edited. In the SQL, all references to the `countries` table have been replaced with references to `sports`.

At least now there's some (rather vague) description of the desired behavior.

Get a list of values from `mytag`, `mytag2` and `mytag3` columns from all rows in `sports` table, as a single column. And then collapse that list of values into a distinct list, along with count of the number of times the tag appears. The most frequently appearing tag values should be listed first.

We can do that:

```
 SELECT t.mytag AS alltag
      , COUNT(1) AS cnt
   FROM ( SELECT t1.mytag 
            FROM sports t1
           UNION ALL
          SELECT t2.mytag2
            FROM sports t2
           UNION ALL
          SELECT t3.mytag3
           FROM sports t3
        ) t
  GROUP
     BY t.mytag
  ORDER
     BY COUNT(1) DESC
      , t.mytag DESC
```

If that isn't right, then we we need to modify that query.

The next part of the specification is ambiguously vague...

*"use that value and check it with the Name column and is if any of these values match and if they do display the information from that row"*

Let's assume (for a moment) that the resultset returned by the previous query is what we wanted, and that it's conveniently available in a table named **`c`**.

To "use that value and check it with the Name column", we can do something like this:

```
 SELECT c.alltag
      , c.cnt
   FROM c
   JOIN sports s
     ON s.name = c.alltag
  ORDER
     BY c.cnt DESC
      , c.mytag DESC
```

The reference to the fictious table **`c`** can replaced with an inline view, the result returned by the first query:

```
 SELECT c.alltag
      , c.cnt
      , s.sportid
      , s.name
      , s.mytag
      , s.mytag2
      , s.mytag3
   FROM ( 
          SELECT t.mytag AS alltag
               , COUNT(1) AS cnt
            FROM ( SELECT t1.mytag 
                     FROM sports t1
                    UNION ALL
                   SELECT t2.mytag2
                     FROM sports t2
                    UNION ALL
                   SELECT t3.mytag3
                    FROM sports t3
                 ) t
           GROUP
              BY t.mytag
           ORDER
              BY COUNT(1) DESC
               , t.mytag DESC
        ) c
   JOIN sports s
     ON s.name = c.alltag
  ORDER
     BY c.cnt DESC
      , c.alltag DESC
      , s.sportid DESC
```

The specification doesn't give any explanation, or any indication, that a self-join of the `sports` table to itself is required. And no mention of why we would need to check for `'football'` in mytag, mytag2 or mytag3.

That bit of the original query is confusing. Given that there's no mention of why that might be required, we've omitted the self-join and any other predicates that restrict rows to be returned.

Everything in the query should be there for a reason. If we can't explain the reason for a SQL construct should be included in a query, then that construct doesn't belong in the query.

---

And (again)...  providing **example data** and the **expected output** would go a long way towards providing a specification that could be understood. That would give us a way to determine what constructs need to be in the query, as well as giving a reference to test against, to *verify* that the query is returning the expected result.

Without that, we're just guessing.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)